# CSS layout with stretching background

Tags: css, html

I have this design layout that has a gradient background in the content container.

the gradient is a solid color on the left and right and gradient to white near the center. (horizontal gradient)

I have three images left-solid.png and a right-solid.png for extending the left and right of the content area if the viewing area is larger.  I have main-gradient.png as the background for the main content and is a fixed size of 900px

Is there a way to lay this out without using a html table?

It looks like I need three columns of some sort

[leftcolumn][contentcolumn][rightcolumn]

rightcontent= can stretch and filled with right-solid.png repeat-x
content = 900px filled with main-gradient.png as background no repeat
leftcontent = canstrech and filled with left-solid.png repeat-y

any suggestions?

Comment: a simple inline-block layout can work, other choices are floating layout, ...

Comment: I think you should consider learning SVG. Replace all these .png with SVG if you want a truly scalable performant page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can achieve a multi-column layout without using tables.  In fact, using tables is semantically incorrect.  This very thing is one of the reasons CSS was created.

**Using the following HTML structure:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Then you could do this in CSS:**

```
.left, .middle, .right {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This will tell the div's to appear next to each other.  Additional CSS styles will be needed as well, like width properties for each column (preferable to use percents).

**Another option for CSS would be:**

```
.left, .middle, .right {
   float: left;
}
```

This will also tell the div's to appear next to each other, but it does it a very different way.

---

A further note is that you don't need to use images for your gradient.  You can do gradients using CSS.  Take a look at http://www.colorzilla.com